# Counting unique event counts in BQ, but GA4 showing event counts that BQ isn't

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I've got a query set up to pull in all distinct event counts for 3 specific events, and I have it showing me campaign name, source, and medium. However when I pull the report and look at it in Looker, and then compare it to GA4, I notice that I'm missing campaigns.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT 
  event_name, 
  event_date, 
  traffic_source.medium, 
  traffic_source.name, 
  traffic_source.source,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(traffic_source.medium, traffic_source.source)) AS event_count, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN ep.key = 'sr_posting_id' THEN ep.value.int_value ELSE NULL END) AS sr_posting_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ep.key = 'page_title' THEN ep.value.string_value ELSE NULL END) AS page_title
FROM 
  `nth-glider-369017.analytics_316822874.events_*` e 
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_params) AS ep
WHERE 
  event_name IN ("sr_job_application_started", "sr_job_application_continued", "sr_job_completed_application")
GROUP BY 
  event_name, 
  event_date, 
  traffic_source.medium, 
  traffic_source.name, 
  traffic_source.source;
```

But I'm not sure why GA4 is showing the event, but BQ isn't. Is it because of me trying to do unique count? I know GA4 is counting every instance, but it's double counting every event, so my numbers are inflated. I'd rather have unique counts.